# Is there a definitive list of properties that can be updated using the JS SDK?

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

After reading through the docs for the REST API and the JS SDK, as well as the [class definitions](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html) for the newer partially complete lib on GitHub, I've been unable to find a definitive list of properties that can be updated via the JS SDK when using the [.update() method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#update). The only two shown are `ActivitySid` and `FriendlyName` - and the other docs have different casing on these properties. I thought casing might not be important, but the source for the [JSSDK](http://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.20/taskrouter.min.js) shows `ActivitySid`. Can someone please point me in the direction of what properties are actually available with the JSSDK? I'm assuming the best bet is that they match the [properties listed here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp/blob/master/src/Twilio/Rest/Taskrouter/V1/Workspace/WorkerOptions.cs#L207-L232) if someone could confirm?

*Note: If you're from Twilio and see this, I'd be happy to open a PR with documentation corrections if it's possible. Otherwise, in the description of `update()` below - `ActiveSid` isn't a thing and it'd be helpful to see a list of properties for methods or at least a link to them.*

> Updates properties of a Worker. There are properties of a Worker, such as **ActiveSid**, FriendlyName, etc.

Thanks!